# What's wrong with this method name in php?

Tags: php, get

So, I have a piece of PHP code, which seems to work, but when it tries to compose a method name like this:

```
> $__GET ['action']()
```

This won't work...

action has a value 'clicked'

Whole line of code where the wanna be method name is stands like this:

```
> $controller = $controller->$__GET ['action']();
```

And yes, this is me trying to learn MVC.

Comment: no 2 underline! that is only one! use this: `$_GET['action']`

Answer (score 0):

First, no use two underscore just one. Second not using just ' but [].
For exemple : $_GET['name'].

Learn the basic php. I think is a good way.

And not use directly $_GET. Use a filter (htmlspecialchar ...)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$_GET['action']` instead of `$__GET['action']`.

You could also try to wrap the variable in curly brackets: `$controller = $controller->{$_GET['action']}();`